# Display div near the scrollbar

Tags: html, css

```css
.container{
  height: 700px;
  width:100%;
}
.need-help-qu {
  background-color:#042E49;
  color:#ffffff;
  padding:0px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
  -o-transition: all .8s ease;
  transition: all .8s ease;
  float:left;
  height:28px;
}
.need-help {
  float:left;
  background-color:#06507D;
  color:#ffffff;
  padding:5px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.need-help-full {
  right:-95px;
  position:fixed;
  top:40%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .8s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .8s ease;
  -o-transition: all .8s ease;
  transition: all .8s ease;
}
.need-help-full:hover {
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class"container">
  Test sscroll
</div>
<div class="need-help-full">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="need-help-qu p-n-b">?</span>
    <span class="need-help text-sm p-n-r">NEED A HELP</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I have one div with the text and '?' sign at right side center with fix position. When user hover on '?' sign the div comes out from right to left with transition (like social icon). It is working perfectly.

But when scrollbar comes in small screen the whole div come over the scrollbar instead of near the scrollbar.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please show your code effort.

Comment: Hello check my updates

Comment: i checked. its working fine

Comment: yes but when scrollbar comes that div comes over the scrollbar instead of near the scrollbar

Comment: There is no scrollbar displayed in you code

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
.need-help-full {
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: i did but that div fade out.

Comment: Adjust the position of that div and maybe on hover you can change z-index to 2 or something

Comment: position must be fix as it is sticky side button.